# Verse: If I create a hotspot link to a nested chapter, does the story return to the hotspot or the parent chapter?

Tags: video-editor

In the Verse Story Editor, if I create a hotspot link to a nested chapter, does the story return to the hotspot when the nested chapter finishes playing, or does the story return to the "parent" chapter above the nested chapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The story returns to the hotspot and continues from there. If you're creating a story with Verse, it's important to understand this behavior so you have creative control over the flow of your story.
[image]